# how to get current activity of the webview in android

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, android-webview

I'm using Webview in my app , i have a simple website, it has two buttons such as Female and Male , if user click that button i want to show the toast message using android app to users which button they clicked

This is my Webview content

[image]

I wanted to know that how to get current activity from the webview and i have another doubt also. how to get the current page url in my android app . for example . if give url like www.stackoverflow.com , the user can browse wherever they want , but at particular time , i need to find out user is in which page.?

Thanks in advance. if this question has any mistakes please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
private String mUrl = "";
...
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
{
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
    {
        mUrl = url;
    }
});
```